# MongoDB script to backup replication set locally to a ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: mongodb

I would like to make a Daily Backup of my MongoDB from a replication set running from ubuntu 14.04 server.

End goal would be to get a daily backup and write the backup to a remote or local share - ubuntu.

Can I batch the mongodump command?

Please help me on this

Comment: There are multiple supported [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/) documented in the MongoDB manual. You'll want to read up on the caveats of different approaches, but `mongodump` is generally only suitable for smaller deployments where data isn't significantly greater than memory. A `mongodump` forces all data to be read through your `mongod`, which could have a significant effect on your working set / performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute `mongodump` from the remote server as mentioned below:

```
mongodump --host <ip-of-mongodb-server> --port <port-number-of-mongod> --out <some-directory>
```

This is required mongo server to be accessible from the remote server.

This dump file can be then compressed and archived on remote host or s3.

If the mongo server is not accessible from remote host, in that case you can execute `mongodump` on local mongodb server and copy it to remote or local share.

Comment: FYI, as of MongoDB 3.2 `mongodump` now supports [`--gzip`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--gzip) and [`--archive`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--archive) options so you no longer need separate steps to compress and/or combine dumps into a single archive file.